# Designing a RESTful API for managing resources as directories and files

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I am designing a *RESTful API* that deals (among others) with managing directories and files.
Due to some tricky business rules (listed below) I have some troubles in finding a good structure of the resources and a good URI design...

- There are many directories.
- A directory has many files.
- The list of files can be accessed only from their parent directory.
- A specific file can be accessed "globally" (by its id only)
- Files can be created, but the client should not be able to specify the parent folder (as new files are saved in a special directory and can only be moved later etc.)

Here's a possible URI design:

Get all directories:
*GET /api/directories*

Get properties a directory:
*GET /api/directories/{directoryId}*

Get files within a directory:
*GET /api/directories/{directoryId}/files*

Get a file:
*GET /api/files/{fileId}*

Delete a file:
*DELETE /api/files/{fileId}*

Create a file:
*POST /api/files*

Is this an awkward design? If yes, why?
Also, if it were to document this *RESTful API*, this would be a bit awkward too:

---

**Directories resource**
*Resource URI:*
/api/directories

*Possible operations:*

- *GET /api/directories*
- *GET /api/directories/{directoryId}*

*Links to other resources:*
(?) How to write this?
There is a link to the **Files** resource, but that is accessible only when using the second operation.

---

**Files resource**
*Resource URI:*
(?) ... there are two URIs... one for "get all" ("or get many") and one for the rest of the operations.

*Possible operations:*

- *GET /api/directories/{directoryId}/files*
- *GET /api/files/{fileId}*
- *DELETE /api/files/{fileId}*
- *POST /api/files*

*Links to other resources:*
Link to **Directory** resource - note the *singular* here (?)
Strictly speaking, there is no **Directory** resource, but there is a **Directories** one - should I treat these two (Directory VS Directories) separately? please see the question at the end. 
Also, this link is available only in the first two operations... How to be more precise when specifying this?

---

---

Also, I've seen that some RESTful API documentations have separate entries for the **collection**-like resource and the **instance / element**-like resource (for example, see [this](https://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/reference-resources)).
Is such a granular documentation preferable? I guess one advantage would be that the "Links to other resources" (or "related resources") section of the documentation would be more precise. Or am I wrong?

---

Any idea is appreciated!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that what you have is particularly awkward. If it were me, I would support these URLs:

```
GET /directories

GET /directories/{directoryId}    // includes a link to the files in the directory, such as /files?directoryId={directoryId}
GET /directories/{directoryId}?expand=files    // includes a child collection with links to each individual file resource, and possibly other metadata as well

GET /files
GET /files?directoryId={directoryId}
POST /files

GET /files/{fileId}
DELETE /files/{fileId}
```

The `/directories/{directoryId}/files` paradigm is common, but not my favorite. If the user wants the files for a directory, they can use a query parameter on `/files`. If they want the files at the same time as the directory, they can use a query parameter on `/directories/{directoryId}`.

This is, of course, all subjective. Without knowing all the specifics, nobody's going to be able to give you a canonically correct answer.

As far as the documentation goes, there's no hard-and-fast structure. If you don't like what you have, change it to avoid the awkwardness. Also, you do have several Directory instances. Each resource that gets returned from `/directories/{directoryId}` is a Directory.